# Android actionbar tabs + swipe view pager navigate from one tab to another dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-actionbar-compat

I have implemented android appcompat actionbar with swipeable tab views using viewpager. I have set two tabs (two fragments). On first fragment (First tab) , I have a button click listener. In this button click listener I need to show the second tab. Though I can swipe between the tabs, I want to call second tab on button click in first tab. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the solution.
On button click listener in first tab,
I set actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);

This takes me to the second tab :)